# Consuming web api using angular js with c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to consume web api using AngularJs to create a dashboard with c# . I succeed to consume the web api but when I want to add angular Js to create my Dashboard nothing appears. I can't figure out what is the problem.

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("DemandeApp", []); app.controller("DemCreditController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:2573/api/demandes")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.labels = [];
             $scope.data = [];
             angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
                 $scope.labels[key] = value.libelle;
                 $scope.data[key] = value.quantite;
             }
         );

         }); 

 });
```

index.html :

```
<body ng-app="DemandeApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemCreditController">

        <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
                chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" ></canvas> 
</div></body>
```

Comment: you need to push the data to array

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code to push the data to your array,

```
$http.get("http://localhost:2573/api/demandes")
   .then(function (response) {
       $scope.labels = [];
       $scope.data = [];
       angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
          $scope.labels.push(value.libelle);
          $scope.data.push(value.quantite);
       }
);
```

Comment: It seems you don't need a key to push value to your $scope.data array. I'm updating the answer accordingly please give a try.